# Dynamic react back button based on current location

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm implementing a back button in react which should change the path according to the current route, something like:

```
<Button path={pathMap.get(location.pathname)} />
```

And it should return the exact url.

The tricky part is that i should be able to match pages like */page/subpage* and differentiate them from */page/child/subpage*

I was trying to use **useRouteMatch** from **react-router** but i don't know if there's a way to tell it that the path should contain a pattern instead of exactly match it.

How can i accomplish that?